# if we only have access to phpMyAdmin what's the best way to backup the entire db?

Tags: mysql, backup, phpmyadmin

For someone that is not used to mySQL, when using [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) administration program, what is the recommended setup to backup the entire database with all tables and with data?

[image]

Comment: Is this MySQL in a LAMP environment, or WAMP?

Comment: @Cory does it matter? I mean I don't know so, I'm asking.

Comment: @Cory Dee if it was WAMP/XAMP I would have access to the shell ;) and it's not LAMP as well, it's a normal Shared Apache Hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of those options are fine, but check the Structure -> "Add DROP TABLE..." and "Add CREATE PROCEDURE", then Data -> "Extended inserts" (this decreases loading time when re-inserting the data and isn't essential). Then click "Save as file" and export, the rest of the options are suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your database is large and you're having problems with phpMyAdmin timing out.  If that's the case, and you don't have shell access, then you may have to write a PHP script, which executes a mysqldump command, and then call it asynchronously so there is no browser timeout issue.  It would be a sloppy workaround, but if the access is limited, something like that may be your only option.

Answer (score 0):

Although it has it's places, phpmyadmin's strong suit is not database backups.

Having said that, if your database is small, using the default settings via an .sql export should be fine.

If your database is large (i.e. more than a couple MB) and/or you care about it, backups should be done on the server level via logical copy, or by doing a mysqldump.